# Why is this code not reaching the 10-cycle $digest loop limit?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

According to http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/:

> *This is the **dirty-checking**. Now that all the `$watch` have been checked there is something else to ask: Is there any `$watch` that has been updated? If there is at least one of them that has changed, the loop will fire again until all of the `$watch` report no changes. This is to ensure that every model is clean. Have in mind that if the loop runs more than 10 times, it will throw an exception to prevent infinite loops.*

From my understanding, if I put this in my view:

```
{{ date }}
```

and this in my controller

```
$interval(function () { 
    $scope.date = new Date(); 
}, 1)
```

what *should* happen is:

1. $interval invokes my fn and triggers a $digest loop;
2. the $watcher for `date` reports its value has changed;
3. no more $watchers, but due to "dirty" state, $watchers are asked again;
4. the $watcher for `date` reports its value has changed again (since it's being changed each 1ms)
5. so on until 10 cycles, then error

but this is not the case. Code runs fine, view is updated all the time and no errors are thrown.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never hit the limit of 10 digest cycles because each time $interval runs it starts a new cycle.

Check out the section titled "Integration with the browser event loop" in the [Angular developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

In your scenario, $interval is generating a new browser event. The event results in Angular's `$apply()` function being run. This process completes. Then on the next interval, a new event is generated and the process starts over.

[image: Angular's event loop]

Comment: Ok, I think I just learned something new about JavaScript: I was assuming setInterval may overlap if the callback takes more time than the interval; but doing a quick test I see that if this happens, the invocations are serialized. So $timeout is doing the same. Right?

Comment: Correct. As such, when the "timeout" event (or any other event: click, onload, etc.) occurs, the browser turns over execution to our "event handler" (callback). The browser waits for our code to complete, re-renders the DOM, and then processes the next "event".